# How to disable verbose logging of neo4j python driver

Tags: python, neo4j

I have tried to change the logging to the console of the neo4j python module to only display critical messages as follows:

```
neo4j_log = logging.getLogger("neo4j.bolt")
neo4j_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

but I am still getting very verbose logging of every single successful node creation.  I am trying to read in data from Oracle in the hundreds of thousands, and this I am sure is not helping performance.

```
[#F2D8]  S: SUCCESS {'stats': {'labels-added': 1, 'nodes-created': 1, 'properties-set': 3}, 'type': 'w', 't_last': 0, 'db': 'neo4j'}
[#F2D8]  S: SUCCESS {'t_first': 0, 'fields': [], 'qid': 539}
[#F2D8]  C: RUN 'CREATE (p:Product) SET p.id = $id, p.preferred_trade_name = $ppn, p.dosage_form=$df ' {'id': 1221, 'ppn': 'product_x', 'df': 'Blank Values'} {}
```

Not that the Oracle part is relevant, as this is a CYPHER logging output but I am basically doing this:

```
def create_graph_nodes_marketing_applications(tx):
    print("Processing marketing application")
    sql = """
            SELECT VERSION_SEQ, DRUG_PRODUCT_ID,  REGISTRATION_SET_ID, REGISTRATION_UID, DOSSIER_REF_NUMBER AS REG_NAME_DETAILS,
                REGISTRATION_NUMBER, NEXT_RENEWAL_DATE, 
                CASE WHEN RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED = 'Y' Then 'No' ELSE CASE WHEN RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED = 'N' Then 'Yes' ELSE NULL END END AS RENEWAL_REQUIRED,
                APPLICATION_TYPE,
                APPLICATION_STAGE,
                COUNTRY_DISPLAY_LABEL,
                DISTRIBUTION_TYPE AS PROCEDURE_TYPE,
                DATA_STATE
                FROM DIM_REGISTRATION_SET WHERE DATA_STATE = 'C' AND FLAG_PASSIVE='0'
                AND APPLICATION_TYPE = 'Marketing Application'                
                
        """
    cursor_ariel.execute(sql)
    for row in cursor_ariel.fetchall():
        r = reg(cursor_ariel, row, False)

        tx.run("""
               CREATE (m:MarketingApplication:Registration) 
               SET  m.id                    =   $id,
                 
                    m.REGISTRATION_SET_ID   =   $rsid,
                    m.DRUG_PRODUCT_ID       =   $dpid,
                    m.REGISTRATION_UID      =   $ruid,
                    m.COUNTRY               =   $country,
                    m.PROCEDURE_TYPE        =   $proc,
                    m.REG_NAME_DETAILS      =   $rnd,
                    m.APPLICATION_TYPE      =   $apptype,
                    m.APPLICATION_STAGE     =   $appstage,
                    m.DATA_STATE            =   $state, 
                    m.RENEWAL_REQUIRED      =   $renewal,
                    m.NEXT_RENEWAL_DATE     =   $renewal_date""",
                    id                      =   r.VERSION_SEQ,
                    rsid                    =   r.REGISTRATION_SET_ID,
                    dpid                    =   r.DRUG_PRODUCT_ID,
                    ruid                    =   r.REGISTRATION_UID,
                    country                 =   r.COUNTRY_DISPLAY_LABEL,
                    proc                    =   r.PROCEDURE_TYPE,
                    rnd                     =   r.REG_NAME_DETAILS,
                    apptype                 =   r.APPLICATION_TYPE,
                    appstage                =   r.APPLICATION_STAGE,
                    state                   =   r.DATA_STATE,
                    renewal                 =   r.RENEWAL_REQUIRED,
                    renewal_date            =   r.NEXT_RENEWAL_DATE
               )
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your question! You're mentioning the Neo4j driver and reading data from Oracle, so I'm not sure I completely understand your setup. Would you mind adding some details, please?

Comment: I am reading in a cursor using cx_Oracle, iterating over each row and executing CREATE statements in neo4j to create nodes, using the details from each Oracle row.  The Oracle part is irrelevant, it is more that the neo4j driver is pumping out messages to the console on every succesful CYPHER transaction.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but if you change the logger name to just "neo4j", does it work?
Also, what version of the driver are you using?

Comment: 4.1.dev0 according to python

Comment: just neo4j seems to do it, thanks ;-)

Comment: Let me convert my comment to an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based [on the 4.x driver sources](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/8f708fe9374f7e6bdfdf84ff611f266a8a5e9344/neo4j/io/_bolt3.py#L62), I believe the logger is just named "neo4j".